# 16-channel multiplexer & python

Tags: python, esp8266, micropython

Update 4/5/22
Equipment:  ESP8266 board, CD74HC4067 16-Channel Multiplexer

Code Platform:  micropython using Thonny on RPi transmitting over USB cable.

Project Goal:  16 individual photo-resistors to trigger individual LEDs or Relays.

Code:
Opening Line...

```
from machine import Pin, ADC
from time import sleep_ms

s0 = Pin(16, Pin.OUT) # assigns s0 on multiplexer to D0 pin on ESP8266
s1 = Pin(5, Pin.OUT)  # D1
s2 = Pin(4, Pin.OUT)  # D2
s3 = Pin(2, Pin.OUT)  # D4
SIG_pin = ADC(0)  # assigns SIG on multiplexer to A0 pin on ESP8266
```

to test the code, I ran

```
val = Sig_pin.read()
print(val)
```

and I get a value which reflects an output... i'm not sure from which of the (16) channels.  If i comment 3 out of 4 of the s# pins, I get a change in value as expected... but again, I'm not sure which channel from the active pin.

I have thought about it and I can create a binary directory to use for the channels.

```
mux = [{0b0000},{0b0001},{0b0010},{0b0011}],[{0b0100},{0b0101},{0b0110},{0b0111}],[{0b1000},{0b1001},{0b1010},{0b1011}],[{0b1100},{0b1101},{0b1110},{0b1111}]
```

In arduino, i could use `digitalWrite(pin,channel)` to call for a specific channel, but how can I do this in python?
and then how can I get the `Sig_pin` to read that specific pin & channel?

Comment: To clarify: you have a channel number from 0 to 15, and you want to know how to find the s0, s1, s2, s3 values associated with that number?

Comment: Correct.  That is where I get confused with the coding.  I know s0 would cover addresses (0000-0011), s1 (0100-0111), s2 (1000-1011), & s3 (1100-1111).  How do I get the code to read the output from say address (0101)?

Comment: Based on the article you linked, if you wanted to read from that address, you'd set s0 to 0, s1 to 1, s2 to 0, and s3 to 1.

Comment: That doesn't help answer my question.  In that link of s pins are set LOW, and it cycles through to return a value for each of the 16 pins.  I'm asking how to read the individual inputs.  Where it says '''digitalWrite(controlpin[i], muxChannel[channel[i])''' that is giving me the output from say pin s1 channel (00101).

Comment: Yes, those pins are initially set to LOW. But later in that loop they're setting the pins based on the channel number and the array muxChannels. s0 thru s3 are always outputs.

Comment: Nick, I wasn't understanding what you were talking about, but I understand it now.  My apologies for not understanding it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem.  I was overthinking the process way too much.

```
ch1 = (s0.value(0), s1.value(0), s2.value(0), s3.value(0))
val = Sig_pin.read()
print(val)
```

Setting each of the s# pins to a high low state gives me my binary combination.